# How do I perform simple linear resampling using a ScriptProcessorNode?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, resampling

I'm currently trying to slow down playback rate dynamically using a ScriptProcessorNode. This is the code I've hacked together so far (only handles the left channel):

```js
let processor = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(2**14);
let stored = [];
let currIndex = 0;
let playbackRate = 0.666;

processor.onaudioprocess = (e) => {
    let leftChannel = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    for (let i = 0; i < leftChannel.length; i++) stored.push(leftChannel[i]);
    let outputLeft = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);

    for (let i = 0; i < outputLeft.length; i++) {
        let otherIndex = currIndex + i * playbackRate;
        let completion = otherIndex % 1;
        let otherSampleLow = stored[Math.floor(otherIndex)];
        let otherSampleHigh = stored[Math.ceil(otherIndex)];

        let val = (completion-1)*otherSampleLow + completion*otherSampleHigh;
        outputLeft[i] = val;
    }

    currIndex += Math.floor(leftChannel.length * playbackRate);
};

let osc = audioContext.createOscillator();
osc.frequency.value = 440;
osc.connect(processor);
osc.start();
```

Yet, it sounds like utter garbage for any playback rate smaller than 1. Why is that? Am I too naive thinking that I can slow down an audio signal just by linearly interpolating between the signals?

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6Le7aq42/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, the mistake was writing `(completion - 1)` instead of `(1 - completion)`.